# UWP - inspecting Frame history

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to inspect the history of the navigation stack from the active Frame?

I see `Frame.BackStack`, but during runtime it doesn't seem to have anything useful.

How is this done?

Comment: Sorry I can not find it

Comment: But I use my navigation stack replace the frame stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation history is recorded, but not necessarily the `Frame` property.

If you want to access the navigation record of the window frame, you can use the following method:

```cs
var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
var back = rootFrame.BackStack;
int length = back.Count;
```

As usual, when the application loads, the `MainPage` is loaded into the `rootFrame` as content. If you set up a `Frame` named **MainFrame** inside the `MainPage` and navigate through the page, you can access the history of this `Frame`:

```cs
var back = MainFrame.BackStack;
```